# How do I edit Infopath webparts in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, web-part, infopath

I have full control on a SharePoint 2010 site with an Infopath Web part on it.

I want to edit its content but the relevant ribbons would not show up from the top.

Please help.

Screenshot below:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the list associated with the web-part.
Under the List tab, click "Customize Form."
Inside Infopath, Find the "Page Design" tab.
Under it, one can select the different views to customize upon.